# Updating iframe's src dynamically encodes & ampersand

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe

When I try to create an iframe dynamically with parameters in the URL, javascript encodes them as & instead of leaving them.

Here is my code:

```
    let myIframe = document.getElementById("myiframe");
    let src = 'https://mywebsite.com/?first_name='+firstName+'&last_name='+lastName+'&email='+email;
    myIframe.src =src;
```

However, when I view the URL in the src of the rendered HTML, I get the following:
[https://mywebsite.com/?first_name=firstName`](https://mywebsite.com/?first_name=firstName%60)&`last_name=lastName`&`email=email

MY question is why is the javascript rendering the & as `&amp;`? It's not playing well with my ability to get the parameters from within the iFrame.

Comment: Javascript encodes what? And what's your desired output? Can you clarify your question?

Comment: @Ruvee, updated. Hope that helps?